# jQuery outline textfield to show error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `textfield` and at the moment i disable the submit button when the `textfield` does not `hold three charactes`. What i want to do now is also outline the `textfield` **bold red** and still have the `submit` button disabled, however i cannot seem to be able to outline the `textfield` and disable the submit `button` at the same time.

my code for disabling the submit button is as follows is it possible to be able to outline the `textfield` when the `length is < 3` in this function to?

thankfull for any help

```
$(function() {

        $('input[name="updateMessage"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
        $('input[name="selectMessageForUpdate"]').keyup(function(){
            if($('input[name="selectMessageForUpdate"]').val().length < 3)
            {
                $('input[name="updateMessage"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
            }
            else
            {
                $('input[name="updateMessage"]').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `border` css property along with `attr('disabled')`

Add a class to define the red border, in your css:

```
textarea[name=selectMessageForUpdate].disabled { border:5px solid red }
```

your js:

```
$(function() {

        $('input[name="updateMessage"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
        $('textarea[name="selectMessageForUpdate"]').keyup(function(){
            if($(this).val().length < 3)
            {
                $('input[name="updateMessage"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
                $(this).addClass('disabled'); // ADD THIS
            }
            else
            {
                $('input[name="updateMessage"]').removeAttr('disabled');
                $(this).removeClass('disabled'); // ADD THIS
            }
        });

    });
```

I created a js fiddle and it seems to work...

http://jsfiddle.net/tmjaF/8/

Comment: Ah yes this works for then button but i would like to outline the `textfield` when the characters are `< 3` @andreas

Comment: Yes it works http://jsfiddle.net/Y3rMM/334/ on that link it works dynamically but on my program i have to click else where to get the outline to show :/ any ideas @andreas

Comment: edited my answer with a link to jsfiddle, is that what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9309/discussion-between-shamari-campbell-and-andreas)

Comment: Wait.. are you using input or textarea... ?

Comment: yes it works find in jsfiddle some reason i have to click else where on the page to get the outline to show in my program

Answer (score 0):

He wants to style the textarea, not the submit button. Just add a class to your textarea with the specified markup and remove it when the input is valid. Also check if the input is more than just whitespace.

```
$(function() {
    $('input[name=updateMessage]').attr('disabled','disabled');
    $('input[name=selectMessageForUpdate]').keyup(function(){
        if($('input[name=selectMessageForUpdate]').val().length < 3)
        {
            $('input[name=updateMessage]').attr('disabled','disabled');
            $('input[name=selectMessageForUpdate]').addClass('someClass');
        }
        else
        {
            $('input[name="updateMessage"]').removeAttr('disabled');
            $('input[name=selectMessageForUpdate]').removeClass('someClass');
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to your css:

```
input.indicated_textfield { border: 2px solid red; }
```

Add the addClass and removeClass lines to your Javascript code:

```
$(function() {

    $('input[name="updateMessage"]').prop('disabled', true);
    $('input[name="selectMessageForUpdate"]').keyup(function(){
        if($('input[name="selectMessageForUpdate"]').val().length < 3)
        {
            $('input[name="updateMessage"]').prop('disabled', true);
            $('input[name="selectMessageForUpdate"]').addClass('indicated_textfield');
        }
        else
        {
            $('input[name="updateMessage"]').prop('disabled', false);
            $('input[name="selectMessageForUpdate"]').removeClass('indicated_textfield');
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: I am using jquery-1.7.2.js @elaxsj

Comment: In jQuery 1.6.1+ you should use the prop method instead of attr/removeAttr. The prop method is new from 1.6.1 and is used for changing attributes after the page is loaded. I updated my code accordingly :)

Comment: thanks for that, the disabled still works but the outline for the `textfield` is not working :/ i have check that the `CSS` has been loaded but it still is not showing on the `textfield` @elaxsj

Comment: I accidentally swapped updateMessage and selectMessageForUpdate in the code. Try now.

Comment: still the same does not outline the textfield :/

Comment: yes it works fine in the link but in my program i have to click else where on the page to get the outline to show

Comment: The keyup event should fire imidiately after you press a key. A possible cause of the problem is the use of plugins/code that alters the jQuery events. Do you use any validate plugins etc? Try to temporarily comment out other jQuery plugins and code, and see if it works. It really should work.